# How is creating trigonometric figures on SCSS?

Tags: css, sass, figure

Could anybody help me to understand how to make a right Regular polygon?(This figure must have 20 corners)

Stackoverflow don't support `SCSS` so my example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpbeLB

I used this formula to find tops of [Regular polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon).

Current code output:
[image]

Comment: I fixed code. Is that better?

Comment: you can convert your SCSS into CSS and add it here for the sake of Working Demo. Can you explain your question more better, with a image as well (of what you want to get in Output).

Comment: I want to get right formula on SCSS. This formula should draw regular polygon (20 anguls) This tops of angles should be the centers of circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick fix**

You can simplify the translation you marked in your question as not working correctly to this:

```css
transform: translate($r * cos($mygrad * $j), $r * sin($mygrad * $j));
```

It seems to [work fine](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpbGyp) then.

---

**Alternative solution**

It is easier to let CSS do the rotation for you, as in [this Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZYYBp). I based it off of your example, but modified it quite heavily.

The basic idea is to make use of the CSS [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) directive. Put every circle at the top and then rotate it to the correct position. A smaller example with only 6 circles is included here, the linked Codepen has a variable for the number of circles, as it uses SCSS.

In this demo, the circles are centered on the corners of the regular polygon, but it should be quite easy to change that if you want.

```css
.mainBlock {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.workerCircle {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.workerCircle:nth-of-type(1) { transform: rotate( 60deg) translate(0, -190px); }
.workerCircle:nth-of-type(2) { transform: rotate(120deg) translate(0, -190px); }
.workerCircle:nth-of-type(3) { transform: rotate(180deg) translate(0, -190px); }
.workerCircle:nth-of-type(4) { transform: rotate(240deg) translate(0, -190px); }
.workerCircle:nth-of-type(5) { transform: rotate(300deg) translate(0, -190px); }
.workerCircle:nth-of-type(6) { transform: rotate(360deg) translate(0, -190px); }
```

```html
<div class="mainBlock">
  <div class="workerCircle"></div>
  <div class="workerCircle"></div>
  <div class="workerCircle"></div>
  <div class="workerCircle"></div>
  <div class="workerCircle"></div>
  <div class="workerCircle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, it looks very cool, but I want use transform values for animation that's why I'm using positioning in example

Comment: I have edited my question to include an updated translation formula. Hope this works for you.